# How do I add a bump map to a texture I made in blender?

Tags: texture-painting

This is more of a theoretical question. I was looking around on youtube and saw a video on texture painting and was wondering if I could make it more realistic. I don't want to use the Internet for this because I want to challenge myself and two I just started learning about blender and three my wifi like my imagination is obviously terrible.

Comment: so you hand painted your texture, now you want to make a bump map? Why can't you just paint a bump map too?

Answer (score 10):

### CYCLES

In ***Node Editor*** Add two color textures (*Image Texture* nodes), set one as ***Color*** and the other as ***Non-Color Data***. Connect the second one to the *Height* input of the *Bump* node (set the *Strenght* as you like). Plug it then to the *Normal* input of your *Diffuse* node.
[image]

### BLENDER INTERNAL RENDER

Add two identical textures to separate texture slots. Call the second one *BUMP*. Under *Influence* uncheck *Color* checkbox. Check the ***Normal*** (set its value) and ***RGB to Intensity*** checkboxes.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can totally do that!  I am using a normal map here, along with a texture I already created.  So you should already have a texture set up on your object, looking like this:

[image: Base texture setup]

Select the next texture slot down, and click "New."

[image: Click new]

Open the image you want to use as the normal map.

[image: Open normal map image]

Scroll down to the section titled "Influence," and disable the Color, and enable the Normal portions.

[image: Enable normal, disable color]

Depending on your UV mapping, you might want to switch to Generated instead of UV (if you where using UV, you also have to select the UV map you want to use).  That's what I did here.  Then, change to Material mode to see your texture with the normal map.  Keep in mind that this does not add any geometry, it just changes how it calculates the lighting to make it look 3D.  You can see the effect on the bottom portion of the 3D view.

[image: Final view]