# Are there any tutorials on adding new details to model textures?

Tags: texturing

I want to make part of the skin on my model more detailed so it looks more realistic but I'm not sure how to do it.

Can you use a bump map from somewhere and UV map that way? Or is there more to it.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60644/how-do-i-add-a-bump-map-to-a-texture-i-made-in-blender

Comment: try using texture painting, and then also find some alpha textures of skin and use them for it, here are a lot for free http://pixologic.com/zbrush/downloadcenter/alpha/

Comment: @Galaxy nah he wants to paint it, but not through procedural textures

Comment: @galaxy thank you, I will try this option

Comment: @michael ben david thank you, these look like they might work